# How to split screen inside of grid in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, split, grid

I'm using reactjs and I want to split my grid area in to 2 fields. I tried but couldn't find any better solution. Do anyone know how to do that?

Here is the image and it shows how do I want to make the divided components

[image: image with divided components]

this image showing area is also in a grid(half of the screen). If the question is not clear, please inform.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: There was wrong way I used Grid. I got it solve. My mistake. Thank you.